# Translate SQL query to JQPL with dates

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpql

I have the next query in Postgre SQL:

```
select * from students
where ((last_date + INTERVAL '60 day') - now()) < INTERVAL '30 day'
```

How can it be translated to JPQL? I know I can use native queries in Java, but I was wondering for JQPL right now. Also 60 and 30 will be variables in application.properties, but I wrote it like this for simplicity.

Comment: To do this from JPQL you will have to do the date manipulations from your Java code, then bind the date values using placeholders.  Note that there may be a timezone issue if you go this direction.

Comment: Thank you! I will try that using ```setParameter()```